# Can we use azure blob storage for scylladb backups?

Tags: azure, backup, azure-blob-storage, scylla

As per the scylladb doc `scylla-manager` is the tool we should use to take our backups.
But as per the latest version of scylla-manager (ie `2.2`) it only seems to support `AWS S3` and `Google Cloud Storage Bucket`.
Is there some way to use `scylla-manager` to upload our backups to `Azure Blobstorage` ?
or
any other way which is at least equally efficient as `scylla-manager` to upload backups to `Azure Blobstorage` ?

Answer (score 2):

We just coded and merged it, it's under tests now. Will be part of manager 2.3

Answer (score 2):

Azure Blobstorage is now supported as a backup location using Scylla Manager 2.4, which was released last week.

- [Release notes](https://www.scylladb.com/product/release-notes/scylla-manager-2-4/)
- Setting up AzureBlobStorage as your [backup location](https://manager.docs.scylladb.com/stable/backup/setup-azure-blobstorage.html)
- Scylla Manager 2.4 also provides an ansible playbook to automate the [restore from backup](https://manager.docs.scylladb.com/stable/restore/index.html)

**Note:** Scylla Manager metrics undergo some refactoring, hence you will need Scylla Monitoring 3.8 ([docs](https://monitoring.docs.scylladb.com/stable/) / Repo [tag](https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-monitoring/releases/tag/scylla-monitoring-3.8.0)) in order to view the Manager metrics in the Manager dashboard in Scylla Monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Blobstorage is not yet integrated into Scylla Manager. While it is in the near-term roadmap, we do not yet have it associated with a particular release or date.